# Why does my Firefox profile folder keep showing up in Recently Used (files/folders)?

Tags: nautilus, firefox, zeitgeist

In "**Privacy** and Activity Mgr", (I would think) the following are my relevant settings:

[image]

[image]

yet in `Nautilus`, my **Firefox profile folder** shows up (usually as the first entry) in the **Recently Used** (file/folder) list:

[image]

- How can I *prevent* the **Firefox profile folder** from showing up in **Recently Used**? Why are my "**Privacy**" settings *not* honored?

Answer (score 0):

The Gtk File Open Widget does not look into the Privacy settings when logging or displaying the "Recently Used" folders.

To manually remove the entries and disable entries, you have have a [look at this Webupd8 blog post](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/nautilus-36-how-to-clear-recent-files.html)

Comment: seems odd (or like a bug)...

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: Gtk needs to be informed about it.

Comment: ok, let's just assume that's the way it is (I can roughly follow); can you suggest a way to categorically prevent the FF profile folder from popping up there? I mean, what's the point of doing it manually, if it'll pop up immediately again?